# How to block the executable file upload in web server

Tags: security, web-applications, upload, mod-security

I am working on a web app project to block all the file executable from file upload.
Example: user can upload, txt, png, image and video files and not any executable scripts like, Perl, Python, exe, PHP, .so, .sh  files.

If it is a PHP file, then I strstr for "<?php" tag, If this tag is present, then it is PHP file. How can we find the same for other script/executable files?

Edit: Some time hackers will upload the malicious files using .png or .jpg extn, so what is the pattern to check inside the files?

Comment: Look at the file(1) and magic(5) man pages for helpful hints.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making your own checks you make use of an existing library and you ***block everything that does not register as a desired format***.

Most such libraries guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain [*signatures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) or [*magic byte sequences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) at specific positions within the file.
Other libraries may be more specialised and will for example only identify image or  video formats.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.fileinfo.php
- https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html

The `file` programme is a command line tool for identification of file types.

After the first pass where you identify and accept only the desired file formats you should then make all files that are not rejected go through an **antivirus scanner**.

Depending on you use cases you may decide to strip the original file name extension and/or even the complete file name that was provided during the upload and assign the mime-type that was detected rather than rely on user provided properties.